# Don't see banner ads on the emulator while testing. Error: Ad failed to load : 3

Tags: android, admob, ads

I am trying to test banner ads in my application. But it doesn't show the ads in my test app on the emulator and gives the following errors:-

I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 3

W/ConnectionStatusConfig: Dynamic lookup for intent failed for action: com.google.android.gms.ads.service.CACHE

W/ConnectionStatusConfig: Dynamic lookup for intent failed for action: com.google.android.gms.ads.service.START

Can you please let me know how to fix this and see the banner ads in my test app?

NOTE: I was able to see the banner ad with using Demo Banner ad unit provided on https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads but not with creating a banner ad unit.

My JAVA code is as follows:-

```
package com.devdroid.adsample;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    AdView adView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        adView = findViewById(R.id.adView);

        MobileAds.initialize(this);

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
}
```

XML is as follows:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        app:adSize="BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest is as follows:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AdSample"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="@string/app_id"
            />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Strings.xml is as follows:-

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">AdSample</string>
    <string name="app_id">XXXXXXXX</string>
    <string name="banner_ad_unit_id">XXXXXXXX</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: where is your code, or do we have to guess?

Comment: @BuratinoApps I have added my Java and XML codes in the body.

Answer (score 1):

You have an empty line with app_id in your string.xml file added a test app_id instead of `xxxxx` `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713` and banner_unit `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111`

If you are testing an application, then you need to specify test values ​​there, and if you have specified the data of the real application and the banner but your application is not published in the play store, then you will not see ads before publication. You only need to test with test values!

If the banner shows using test values, then change it to real values ​​and publish it in the play store. After it is published, you add a link to your application to admob and ads will be shown without problems.

Comment: Those lines are not empty. I do have app_id and banner_ad_unit_id there. I changed them to XXXXXXXX here just to not share those ids publicly.

Comment: I have seen a youtube tutorial from someone where they use generated ids and everything seems to work fine there. The link is [https://youtu.be/g9rVra5wG7s](https://youtu.be/g9rVra5wG7s). Language is Hindi. Might be difficult to understand if you don't know the language.

Comment: Does the banner show with test values?

Comment: Yes, the banner can be seen with test values. I wanted to try out the case though with the generated ids.

Comment: You will see but after publishing in the play market or in another app store. If my answer helped you please mark it as a solution.

Comment: We can also use our own ad units to get test ads. Refer to https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads. The steps here don't work for me though. I posted this link above as well.

Comment: So why did you send me this instruction, instead of carefully looking at how to set up a test ad with your own data? To begin with, carefully study it yourself, everything is described in detail in it.

Comment: It worked for me now both on the emulator and my android phone. Looks like it needed approval of my admob account to work. Earlier when I was trying, my admob account was not yet approved.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me now when my admob account got approved. Both on the emulator and my android phone with my own ad units. Steps were followed from https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads

It seems like earlier it was not working because my admob account was not approved.